# make jquery code work for dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

This piece of code works for all existing html drop downs but how to make it work for dynamically added drop downs too

Here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('select.select').each(function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    if ($('option:selected', this).val() != '') {
      title = $('option:selected', this).text();
      $(this)
        .css({
          'z-index': 10,
          'opacity': 0,
          '-khtml-appearance': 'none'
        })
        .after('<span class="select">' + title + '</span>')
        .change(function () {
          val = $('option:selected', this).text();
          $(this).next().text(val);
        })
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    initDropDowns();

    function initDropDowns(){
      $('select.select').each(function () {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        if ($('option:selected', this).val() != '') {
          title = $('option:selected', this).text();
          $(this)
            .css({
              'z-index': 10,
              'opacity': 0,
              '-khtml-appearance': 'none'
            })
            .after('<span class="select">' + title + '</span>')
            .change(function () {
              val = $('option:selected', this).text();
              $(this).next().text(val);
            })
        }
      });
    }

    // on dropDowns add --> initDropDowns();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $(document).ready() you need to use $(document).live()

.ready() lets you register a callback that fires when the DOM is ready - this is similar to using window.onload but fires earlier (and you can register more than one callback).

.live() lets you register a callback to a range of events based on a selector, which continually monitors the DOM and will register itself to new nodes that are added.

Comment: live is deprecated since 1.7, removed in jquery 1.9, see http://api.jquery.com/live/ "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."